# jQuery ui menu global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery ui menu and this function to keep track of what menu item is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#menu" ).menu({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.text());
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a way to make their selection into a global scope variable? Currently doing everything in this function is getting messy.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you simply call a function from select options callback and pass the selected item into it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking for but would either of these changes help?

```
var tj_currently_selected_text;

function tj_process_select(event, ui){
  alert('old selected text = '+tj_currently_selected_text);
  tj_currently_selected_text = ui.item.text();

  alert(tj_currently_selected_text);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#menu").menu({
    select: tj_process_select
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you return ui.item.text() out of the function?

Comment: Yes, the `var tj_currently_selected_text;` line being called outside the function makes that variable global. Now if that variable is set inside of a function, without "var" before it, it will set it globally. What I normally do is create a master object for my apps then throw all global variables in that. Such as `var my_obj = my_obj||{};` then `my_obj.anything_inside` can be set and it's automatically available globally. You can also use `window.my_global_var` without setting anything outside of the function first and it will be available afterwards.